# Proving recurrence relation for the Beta function

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, special-functions, beta-function

How can I prove the following: $$B(x+1,y)=B(x,y) \cdot \frac{x}{x+y}$$ Does anyone know the proof? I know the Beta function is related to the Gamma function, but I would like to prove it with partial integration. When I used partial integration, I got stuck.

Comment: A good starting point for making this question more substantive is to indicate what you already know about the Beta function. For instance, what definition(s)  do you have? Do you know how the Beta function is related to the Gamma function?

Comment: Integrate by parts & rearrange.

Comment: I know the Beta function is related to the Gamma function, but I would like to prove it with partial integration. When I used partial integration, I got stuck.

Comment: It would be helpful, then, to edit your question body to include your attempt to apply partial integration. (It doesn't seem to me that partial integration will suffice by itself, but it does provide a result which is useful for making progress.) At the very least, it would be a good idea to indicate which integral representation you have in mind---there's a few!

Comment: I found the solution myself. Thank you for helping!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the right hand of the equation:
$$B(x,y)\frac{x}{x+y}=B(x,y)\frac{\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x)}}{\frac{\Gamma(x+y+1)}{\Gamma(x+y)}}=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}\frac{\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x)}}{\frac{\Gamma(x+y+1)}{\Gamma(x+y)}}=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y+1)}=B(x+1,y)$$
Here only the definition of the beta function
$$B(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}$$
 and the relation between the gamma functions 
$$\Gamma(x+1)=\Gamma(x)x$$
were applied.

Answer (score 0):

First euler beta function:

$B(z,w) = \int_{0}^{1}t^{z-1}(1-t)^{w-1}dt$

where $z, w \in \{z \space| \space Rez > 0\}$, substitute t with $t=\frac{s}{1+s}$

$B(z, w) =\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{z-1}\space \space dt}{(1+t)^{z+w}}$

Use the partial integration with $zB(z, w)=z\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{z-1}\space \space dt}{(1+t)^{z+w}}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt^z}{(1+t)^{z+w}}$

Then $zB(z, w)=(z+w)B(z+1,w)$ is obtained